# C/C++ multiple scanf in one function

Tags: c++, c, return, scanf

How do I make a function that reads some values from console and then I return them? I mean not a single `scanf`, multiple `scanf` in another function and then return the values.

For example:

```
int main(){
    write();
}

int write(void){
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter an int");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter another int");
    scanf("%d",&b)
    return a,b;
}
```

I know that `C` is not `C++`; I just want an example of `C++`. Here is the full program that I made. I ask this question because I want to optimize my code. The above function I implemented in my program, but I didn't figure out to make it work, only with pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 32

void read(int*x,int*y);

void write(int m[][MAX],int x,int y);

void display(int sir[][MAX],int x,int y);

int main(){
    int x,y,m,n,a,b,i,k;
    int matrice1[MAX][MAX]={0},matrice2[MAX][MAX]={0},result[MAX][MAX]={0},result2[MAX][MAX]={0};
    read(&x,&y); //this is what i want to not use direct addreses if is possible
    write(matrice1,x,y);
    m=x;
    n=y;
    read(&x,&y);
    write(matrice2,x,y);
    system("cls");
    printf("Prima matrice: \n");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(k=0;k<n;k++){
            printf(" %d",matrice1[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    display(matrice1,m,n);
    printf("\nA doua matrice: \n");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        for(k=0;k<y;k++){
            printf(" %d",matrice2[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    display(matrice2,x,y);
    printf("\nSuma matricelor: \n");
    if(x>m){
        a=x;
    }
    else
        a=m;
    if(y>n){
        b=y;
    }
    else
        b=n;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        for(k=0;k<b;k++){
            result[i][k]=matrice1[i][k]+matrice2[i][k];
            printf(" %d",result[i][k]);
            if(matrice1[i][k]%2!=0 && matrice2[i][k]%2!=0){
                result2[i][k]=matrice1[i][k]+matrice2[i][k];
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nSuma matricelor impare<doar daca ambele sunt impare>: \n");
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        for(k=0;k<b;k++){
            printf(" %d",result2[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void write(int m[][MAX],int x,int y){
    int i,k;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        for(k=0;k<y;k++){
            printf("elementul de pe linia %d, coloana %d: ",i,k);
            scanf("%d",&m[i][k]);
        }
    }
}

void read(int*x,int*y){
    printf("\nIntroduceti numarul de randuri a matricei: ");
    scanf("%d",x);
    printf("Introduceti numarul de coloane a matricei: ");
    scanf("%d",y);
    printf("\nIntroduceti elementele matricei.\n");
}

void display(int sir[][MAX],int x,int y){
    int i,k;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        for(k=0;k<y;k++){
            if(sir[i][k]%2==0)
                printf("numar par, pozitia %d,%d: %d\n",i,k,sir[i][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think question should rather be **returning multiple values from a function**

Comment: @Olaf I think your second comment isn't entirely accurate; while this isn't a good question, he's not really asking for any offsite resource.

Comment: I disagree with removal of the C++ tag, as OP is asking about a comparison of `scanf` vs `cin`.

Comment: You can't return more than one value from a C function, this isn't Python. You could, however, pass an array as the first argument and have the function fill a pointer passed as the second argument with the size of the array. You'd call it like this: `int numNums = 0; int readNums[100]; readNumbers(readNums, &numInts, sizeof(readNums) / sizeof(readNums[0]));`

Comment: Here is simple example: http://ideone.com/wzcwkf

Comment: @szczurcio: "How do i make a function ..." is imo asking for a tutorial (aka a howto). But I'm fine if you disagree; there's still some freedom left.

Comment: @szczurcio: In Python you also don't return more than one object from a function. Is is just that the language does automatic packing/unpacking of a tuple for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither C nor C++ functions can *return* multiple values; not that it matters, since neither C nor C++ support multiple assignment either.

With C, you have the following choices:

1. If all the objects are the same type and *logically* related (i.e., a list of grades, temperatures, etc.), pass an array as the function argument, write to elements of the array:

   ```
   void foo( int *arr, size_t arrSize )
   {
     ...
     scanf( "%d", &arr[i] );
     ...
   }
   ```

   which would be called as:

   ```
   int values[N];
   ...
   foo( values, N );
   ```

   Alternately, you can have the function dynamically allocate a block of memory to hold its inputs, and return the pointer to that allocated block:

   ```
   /**
    * Stores inputs to a dynamically-allocated block of memory.
    *
    * Outputs:
    *
    *  arrSize  - Number of array elements allocated
    *  arrCount - Number of array elements assigned
    */
   int *foo( size_t *arrSize, size_t *arrCount )
   {
     *arrSize = INITIAL_SIZE; // some size that covers most of your use cases
     *arrCount = 0;
     /**
      * Allocate the array
      */
     int *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * *arrSize );
     if ( !arr )
        // allocation failed, handle as appropriate
     int val;
     while ( scanf( "%d", &val ) == 1 )
     {
       /**
        * If we've filled the array, extend it by doubling its size
        */
       if ( *arrCount == *arrSize )
       {
         int *tmp = realloc( arr, sizeof *arr * (*arrSize * 2) );
         if ( tmp )
         {
           arr = tmp;
           *arrSize *= 2;
         }
         else
         {
           // failed to extend the array, handle as appropriate
         }
       }
       arr[(*arrCount)++] = val;
     }
     return arr;
   }
   ```

   which would be called as:

   ```
   size_t size = 0, count = 0;
   int *values = foo( &size, &count );
   ...
   free( values ); // need to release the memory when you're done with it
   ```

   Note that C functions cannot return objects of array type; that is, you can't do:

   ```
   int foo(void)[N] // illegal syntax
   {
     int arr[N];
     ...
     return arr; 
   }
   ```

   Nor can you return a pointer corresponding to a local array, since the array ceases to exist once the function exits:

   ```
   int *foo( void )
   {
     int arr[N];
     ...
     return arr; // pointer will be invalid after function exits
   }
   ```

   If the objects have different types, or are not logically part of the same group, then use multiple pointers in the argument list:

   ```
   void foo( int *p1, double *p2 )
   {
     ...
     scanf( "%d", p1 );
     ...
     scanf( "%lf", p2 );
     ...
   }
   ```

   and call it as

   ```
   int bar;
   double bletch;
   ...
   foo( &bar, &bletch );
   ```

C++ gives you some different options:

1. If all the items have the same type and are logically related, use a vector to store them and return the vector:

   ```
   std::vector<int> foo( void )
   {
     std::vector<int> arr;
     size_t i = 0;
     ...
     std::cin >> arr[i++];
     ...
     return arr;
   }
   ```

   and call it as:

   ```
   std::vector<int> values = foo();
   ```

   If the items have different types or are not logically related, then use multiple *references* to those items:

   ```
   void foo( int& bar, double& bletch )
   {
     ...
     std::cin >> bar;
     ...
     std::cin >> bletch;
   }
   ```

   and call it as

   ```
   int x;
   double y;
   ...
   foo( x, y ); // no & operator since we're using references in the called function
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Please note that C and C++ are different languages so the code will also be different.

For C, I'd suggest the following approach:

```
int readInts(int intArr[], size_t maxInts)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < maxInts && scanf("%d", &intArr[i]) == 1) { i++; }
    return i;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int myInts[100];
numInts = readInts(myInts, sizeof(myInts) / sizeof(myInts[0]);
```

In C++ one should avoid manual memory management whenever possible, therefore I'd do this:

```
std::vector<int> readInts()
{
    int x;
    std::vector<int> result;
    while (std::cin >> x)
    {
        result.push_back(x);
    }

    return result;
}
```